# Использование openssl с отладочной информацией

Tags: c++, openssl

Хочу использовать openssl с отладочной информацией. Для этого скачал openssl-1.1.1g, собрал и поставил в /usr/local/lib.

Собираю свое приложение, оно линкуется с /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1.

Но при запуске выдает ошибку:

> relocation error: symbol EC_GFp_nistp256_method version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скачали в смысле склонировали? Видимо, нужно `libctypto` скачать с такими же символами. Введите в терминал `apt install libcrypto` (без ввода), и нажмите дважды `Tab`. Увидите список, там есть `libcrypto++6-dbg`, и целый набор с `OpenSSL`.

Comment: Скачивал командой `wget -c https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1p.tar.gz`. Скачал `libcrypto++6`, посмотрел командой `nm` что там за символы, нужных мне функций с префиксом `EVP_` там нет. Судя по информации о пакете `libcrypto++` совсем другая библиотека, не связанная с 'crypto` которая входит в openssl.

Comment: Да, это же плюсовая, а вам нужно сишная

Comment: как именно собираешь/запускаешь? На вскидку, или хедеры от системной версии используешь вместо своей, или линкуешь со своей, а запускаешь с системной...

Comment: И если цель только в том, чтобы были отладочные символы, то FYI большинство дистрибутивов предоставляют отладочную информацию в пакетах с суффиксом `-debug` или `-dbg`